# TSP Concorde fails with Status 127 Message

Tags: r, solver, traveling-salesman

Trying to use the TSP package interface to solve the famous TSP problem using concorde algorithm is resulting in status 127.
I had placed the path of the concorde executable in concorde_path().
And ran the concorde_help() command which resulted in status 127 warning message.
On running the solve_TSP function the following error is encountered

```
data("USCA312")
solve_TSP(USCA312, method = "concorde", control = list(clo = "-V"))
Used parameters:
clo  =  -V
precision    =  6
exe  =  C:/Users/gourav.trivedi/Downloads/concorde
verbose  =  TRUE
Warning in tsp_concorde(x_, control = control) :
  Concorde can only handle distances < 2^31. Reducing precision for Concorde to 3
Error in tsp_concorde(x_, control = control) : 
  Problems with reading Concorde's output.
Is concorde properly installed?
For details see ? Concorde
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Users/gourav.trivedi/Downloads/concorde" -x -V -o file38087a417c0e.sol file38087a417c0e.dat' had status 127
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows (it runs fine on Linux), but you need to check that:

1) Concorde works on your system. It needs Cygwin (see http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/downloads/downloads.htm). Try to execute an example from the command line interface.

2) The path is correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir can you please share step by step guide for making concorde TSP setup for ubuntu 20.04. I try a lot but not got success. I am following this link http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/downloads/downloads.htm

Comment: I made a setup of concorde in my ubuntu but I don't know how to take input and generate output file and how to see output file

Comment: You need R and the TSP package installed. Then follow the manual page: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TSP/topics/Concorde

Comment: I am a newbie on this, please tell me where can i install R and TSP packages.I am using ubuntu 20.04 and working on nodejs project

Comment: I have a 50 shops and starting location and ending location and its distances. Now I want to solve TSP for this problem

Comment: Here is how you get started: https://github.com/mhahsler/TSP